# Why can I see a website via browser, but with "wget/curl/..." I get "403 Forbidden"?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, wget, response-headers, xcache

A website is normally reachable via browser (Chrome, Firefox, ...), but if I try to access via **wget**/**curl**/... I get the following error:

```
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: CloudFront
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 14:20:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 919
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 *****.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: CDG3-C1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: ****-****==
---response end---
```

I tried making the **wget** request by setting *referer*/*user-agent*/... in the HEADER, but the result doesn't change.

It's probably a **CloudFront Server** protection, which I don't know about.

But before throwing in the towel, I would like to ask the community if there is a solution or other possible tests to do.

Comment: Can anyone please help me understand where is the problem and if there is a solution?